# Cordova/Phonegap AJAX iOS not seem to be getting responses

Tags: android, ios, ajax, cordova, phonegap

I have a phonegap/cordova application and I need help.
The app connects to my client's WordPress sot via REST API to pull subscriber's info and use it to unlock features.

ita working flawlessly on my end (android and ios) however on my client's ios phones, it doesn't seem to work.

any ideas as to why it isn't working on their end and works on all my devices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure they haven't activated the option that allows connection to a whitelisted set of websites only. Anyway, this issue you are reporting is getting more and more common in the recent weeks, it seems Apple has introduced something new to bother developers (even more)? What iOS version are they using?

Comment: They’re on 11.3 but it’s really weird since my iphone is at 11.3 as well

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in the latest version of iOS 11.3, that causes this type of issue. Also do check whether URLs of all the REST APIs given, must be of the the cloud or server on which its hosted.
It can be one of the issue done by mistake.